# Is there a way to use a pull request with cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

With swift 3, many cocoapods have been scrambling to keep up with the changes each beta brings. Sometimes these changes aren't merged into a branch quickly. In those cases, is there a way to use a pull request of a branch?

Example:
https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/pull/187/commits/d791055bc43bba9af8124d2832c2d8cd95ecfc11

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do exactly?  You want to specify this PR as your dependency?

Comment: I'm on Xcode 8 beta 6, which breaks the swift3 branch of this repository. Someone submitted a pull requests which fixes it. I'd like to use that, but am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always specify a specific commit or branch to pull in with your pod file.

So, if you wanted the swift3 branch from the master repo, it'd be as simple as:

```
pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```

However, this pull request did not come from  the master repo.  We need to figure out where it came from.

In this case, it came from [this repo](https://github.com/sammygutierrez/Spring/tree/swift3), so we just need to change what repository it came from (the branch name in that repo is actually the same):

```
pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/sammygutierrez/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```