# Github and Cocoapods - install an unmerged pull request

Tags: github, cocoapods

Is there a way to install an unmerged pull request of a cocoapod?

I really want to use Countdown Label here https://github.com/suzuki-0000/CountdownLabel

but I'm using Swift 4.  The pod uses 'characters' and 'character' which are deprecated.  There is a pull request which has fixed this here https://github.com/suzuki-0000/CountdownLabel/pull/29

I'm pretty new to GitHub so this might be a stupid question but when I try install the Swift 4 version (version 3 as specified) I still get the 'characters deprecated' errors when compiling.  I can see from the code in the pull request that it probably fixes it (removes references to character and characters) but no idea if it can be installed without it being merged?

I did check this answer [Is there a way to use a pull request with cocoapods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261018/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-pull-request-with-cocoapods) but don't think it's applicable in this situation (URL format isn't the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your Podfile:

```
pod 'CountdownLabel', :git => 'https://github.com/ShangZhengtao/CountdownLabel.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Detailed explanation and background in the [Podfile Syntax Guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod).

Comment: thanks  for some reason this didn't work but i've just copied and pasted the changes into the source files now - i can see this approach is generally right though from the docs so not sure why it didn't work

Comment: ah I'd used pod install - i've now run pod update and it worked fine thanks for the help!